# CiviEvent Mass Participant Registration - Blank Page

Tags: wordpress, civievent, registration, participants

WordPress 5.5.3
CiviCRM 5.31.1

### Problem with CiviCRM event (CiviEvent) mass registration

I'm trying to mass register participants as per: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/manual-event-registration/#mass-registrations. However, on clicking `Register participants for event`, it simply redirects me to a blank page titled `New Event Registration`.

What I clicked on:

[image]

Redirected to:

[image]

I've checked 5.32.0 https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.32/release-notes/5.32.0.md release note and there's nothing addressing this issue.

Comment: This is a recent bug. There isn't a full bug-report in Gitlab, but there is a draft fix being discussed/reviewed at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19125

Comment: @TimOtten Yes you're right. Merging the changes from the pull request fixes the problem for me. Thank you. If you could post that as an answer, I'll mark and accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recent regression. A fix has been merged for [5.33 (RC)](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19125) and the upcoming [5.32.2](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19127).